How to show User Control values in the UI when the PostBack is false
I have an ASP.Net application, when the Postback is true, I'm able to see UserControl values in the UI. But when the PostBack is false(when we refresh or load page) the values of UserControl fields are not appearing in UI. (When some OnClick button is clicked we are able to see those Usercontrol values.)
Can someone please help me on this.
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!PostBack)
    {
        LoadProject();
    }
}
LoadProject()
{
    var myUC = (MyUserControl)myUserControl;
    myUC.Date1 = date1; //some date value;
    myUC.Date2 = date2; //some date value;
}
protected button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some functions
    LoadProject();
}

    myUC.Date1 = date1; //some date value;
    myUC.Date2 = date2; //some date value;
}
protected button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some functions
    LoadProject();
}

I have tried adding myUC.Update() after assigning values(the values are visible while debugging code) to my user control but not displaying values in UI. Prompt help is highly appreciated.

Try to study more: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811684/Understanding-The-Complete-Story-of-Postback-in-AS

To me it looks like your code example is completely broken, and wouldn't run.

what MyUserControl actually do with both Date1 and Date2? its hard to tell. i do suspect the problem lies on that particular custom user control instead of your postback thingy - though, you should also double check the aspx file @Page directive's attributes to be sure.. oh and also your example code isn't a valid c# code.

Keep in mind the sequence of events for a user control.
The page load event of the hosting page fires first, and THEN the UC page load event fires.
This means if the UC sets up some default values on page load, they will often overwrite the values you setup on the hosting page.
And keep in mind that private (or public) class members for the UC don't persist values any different then code behind for the hosting page.
This means if the UC is not using controls in the markup with viewstate, then you will have to write code to persist such values on post-backs.
So, let's build a UC that allows the user to enter a start date, and a end date.
Since we using 2 text boxes for this purpose, then viewstate is automatic, and values in the 2 text boxes will retain those values even on post-backs (round trips).
However, we still have to deal with the case in which the main hosting page wants to setup some default values, and if the main page does not setup any values, then we want the UC to setup some values.
So, our UC markup can be this:
    <div style="float:left">
        <h3>Enter Starting date</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"
            TextMode="Date">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin-left:30px">
        <h3>Enter Ending date</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server"
            TextMode="Date">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>

And if the hosting page (page load event) did not setup any values for the UC, then we will have the page load event of the UC do so.
Hence, this code for the UC:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
            // first page load, runs AFTER host page load!
            // check if values been set, if not, setup 
            // a default value

            if (txtStartDate.Text == "")
                DtStart = DateTime.Today;

            if (txtEndDate.Text == "")
                DtEnd = DateTime.Today;
        }

    }

    public DateTime DtStart
    {
        get { return DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text); }

        set {
            DateTime dt = value;
            txtStartDate.Text = dt.ToShortDateString();            
        }
    }
    public DateTime DtEnd
    {
        get { return DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text); }

        set {
            DateTime dt = value;
            txtEndDate.Text = dt.ToShortDateString();            
        }
    }

Note how on first page load, the UC code checks if any values been setup (presumably by the hosting page).
Hence, we now can drag + drop the UC into our host page markup like this:
        <uc1:UDateRange runat="server" ID="UDateRange" />
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Dates"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            />

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

Now in our hosting page, if we don't setup any values, then the UC will do so.
Hence this code behind:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string msg
            = "Start date = " + UDateRange.DtStart.ToLongDateString() + "<br/>" +
              "End date = " + UDateRange.DtEnd.ToLongDateString();
        Label1.Text = msg;

    }

Hence this result:

However, let's change the hosting page to setup some date values on first page load, and hence this code:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            UDateRange.DtStart = new DateTime(2024, 11, 1);
            UDateRange.DtEnd = new DateTime(2024, 11, 1);

        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string msg
            = "Start date = " + UDateRange.DtStart.ToLongDateString() + "<br/>" +
              "End date = " + UDateRange.DtEnd.ToLongDateString();
        Label1.Text = msg;

    }

So, hosting page load fires first, sets up a date range.
However, in the UC page load event, we check if any default values been set, and if yes, then the UC first page load event does not setup any default values.
Hence the result is now this:

Once again, keep in mind that the above works and "retains" the values since we are using a text box to hold the value. If that control had no text box, or say some kind of jQuery.UI date popup, then the values would be lost on each post-back, and that means you would have to write code to push and pull values out of say view state for this to work.
